# how to Parse values from Array?this is my sample array code?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

```
Array
(
    [Action] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => OfferActivationByOfferID
                            [Version] => 1.0
                            [ImagePath] => ./resources
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Ranjith
                            [Version] => 1.0
                            [ImagePath] => ./resources
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

in this array i need [Name] attribute Value for Every Action tag.please do help.

sample output;

1.OfferActivationByOfferID

2.Ranjith

Comment: bot are two separate arrays? or they are sub-array of one single array? Please format array input, because it's confusing.

Comment: they are sub arrays of single array.

Comment: check the changed array structure in your question. Is it right now?

Comment: is this from simplexml? you can use `->attributes()` method for those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are saving array data in some variable. It is very simple :-

```
$data = //Your arraydata
foreach($data['Action'] as $key=> $value){
    echo $value['@attributes']['Name'];
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = //Your full array
$names = array();
// then loop through the array
foreach($data['Action'] as $key=> $value){
    $names[] = $value['@attributes']['Name'];
}
```

So `$names` will have all the names of the original array.